# dismissViewController clear the screen but doesn't dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 screens:

The first call the second with the following code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:kDetailSegue]) {
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadingThread) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
        TagDetailControllerViewController* detailController = segue.destinationViewController;
        detailController.location = self.recentLocation;
    }
}
```

The  `kDetailSegue` is a present modally - presentation default - transition: default

In second ViewController, I'm trying to dismiss the screen:

```
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Are you sure, you want to dismiss your 'navigationController' or your presented viewController ?

Comment: I want to dismiss the current viewController (the second view)

Comment: ypu are presenting it modally and dismissing using navigationcontroller, it wont work because your viewcontroller is not in navigation controller's stack.

Comment: [self presentViewController:origin animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Try this: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:nil];

Comment: Is the second view what the call refers to as ```TagDetailControllerViewController```?

Comment: You just need to call '[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:nil] ;' inside your 'TagDetailControllerViewController'. Thats it..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you want to dismiss in your second view controller, so I will try to present the most likely scenarios:

- If you want to dismiss the view controller presented modally (`TagDetailControllerViewController`), you need to dismiss it modally too.

  This can be achieved by calling in your `TagDetailControllerViewController` itself:

  ```
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  ```

  Which works because, according to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:):

  > If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller.

  Also, if you want to dismiss it directly from the view controller you used to present it, you can do it as follows:

  ```
  [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  ```
- Finally, if what you want is to dismiss a view that was pushed in your `UINavigationController`, then you can just pop it from the stack:

  ```
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  ```

As you can see, **the way a view is dismissed really depends on the way it was presented**.

Comment: Agreed, if you want to dismiss a controller pushed from the navigation controller, then you need to do: [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];

Answer (score 0):

try this

[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

Comment: `presentedViewController`?

Comment: Current viewcontroller